# Azure bugs or am I using npm local packages and private packages hosted on github incorrectly?

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, npm-install

### bug #1) local packages

1. Created a test project "azure_test"
2. In folder "azure_test" ran the command "express --view=hbs app".

> /azure_test/app as all the structure of an npm package, but is in a directory.
>   Essentially a local package.

3. in Azure_test/package.json is declare a dependency to this local package

   "dependencies": {
   "app": "./app"
   }

> a local package as per https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/packages

4. on my windows 10 machine, in folder /azure_test, I run "npm install", "npm start" and all works and expected.
5. save into github
6. In Azure, create an "App Service" and configure Azure to get source directly out of github

this fails. Log file at 
https://purple01test.scm.azurewebsites.net/DebugConsole/?shell=powershell

contains the line

> 26 verbose git clone git://github.com/./app fatal: remote error:

If I remove all the dependencies out of /azure_test/app/package.json and copy these dependencies into /azure_test/package.json (ie: not using local package).  Then all works on Azure, but I lose modularity of local packages (manually copy dependencies to the top level).

So am I using local packages incorrectly and it just happens to work in windows 10 or does Azure have a bug?

I made this test project public. It can be found at https://github.com/johngrabner/azure_test/

### bug #2) private packages hosted in github

```
"dependencies": {
        "purple_shared_enums_pic_pi": "git+https://github.com/johngrabner/purple_shared_enums_PIC_PI.git"
    }
```

This also causes Azure to fail.
If the package hosted in github is public, Azure passed.

So bug #2 appears to be Azure fails to use the github password for dependencies.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Have you [set up continuous deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment) from Github via the Azure portal? Did you have a `web.config` file in your app's root?

Comment: I setup azure to pull from Github directly.  I check this part and it works.  Every update to github get pulled into Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I did some research and found that Docker / Kubernetes is probably a better choice for deployment.  A number of courses and online video listed "no more, it works on my machine, but not in production".

You package your app in Docker, where you specify the exact OS, middleware, etc.  Test on your machine.  Then deploy this image to Azure, AWS, or Google.  Kubernetes manages the spaning of these images.